# Appscript can't run json

Tags: google-apps-script

```
  "pagemap": {
    "cse_thumbnail": [
      {
        "src": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTviYVS-9NyQU80P95iiB8_h2MuM6FM4u7a56V5_KFbD-PNqhbPbZ9KRQDf",
        "width": "263",
        "height": "192"
      }
    ],
    "metatags": [
      {
        "msapplication-tilecolor": "#D70F64",
        "msapplication-config": "none",
        "msapplication-square70x70logo": "https://micro-assets.foodora.com/favicons/fp/square70x70logo.png",
        "viewport": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no",
        "msapplication-square310x310logo": "https://micro-assets.foodora.com/favicons/fp/square310x310logo.png",
        "msapplication-wide310x150logo": "https://micro-assets.foodora.com/favicons/fp/wide310x150logo.png",
        "msapplication-square150x150logo": "https://micro-assets.foodora.com/favicons/fp/square150x150logo.png"
      }
    ],
    "cse_image": [
      {
        "src": "https://images.deliveryhero.io/image/fd-tw/LH/a3pj-hero.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }
```

How to get cse_thumbnail -> src
my code is
-- pagemap.cse_thumbnail[0].src--
Appscript is show me below
--TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined --

Comment: Show your full code please

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the error. It works just fine:

```js
var jsn = {"pagemap": {
    "cse_thumbnail": [
      {
        "src": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com",
        "width": "263",
        "height": "192"
      }
    ],
  }
};

console.log(jsn.pagemap.cse_thumbnail[0].src);
```

Perhaps the error in the way you're tying to get the value. Show this part of your script.